# Azure Devops Test Pipeline LNK1107 When Opening vulkan-1.lib on MSVC but Works fine on GCC

Tags: c++, azure-devops, msbuild, linker, vulkan

Currently have a linker error in an Azure Devops test pipeline:

```
##[error]lib\static\x64\vulkan-1.lib(0,0): Error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x82
lib\static\x64\vulkan-1.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x82 [d:\a\1\s\Rhea\Rhea.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\Rhea\Rhea.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

This only happens when attempting to build on MSVC on the build machine. GCC on the build machine works fine and local machines using MSVC are able to compile just fine.

This is the testpipeline.yml:

```
trigger:
- master

strategy:
  matrix:
    x64-Debug:
      configuration: 'debug'
      architecture: 'x64'
    x64-Release:
      configuration: 'release'
      architecture: 'x64'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true

  - bash: chmod -R 755 ./
    displayName: "Elevate Bash"

#Windows
  - bash: ./vendor/premake/win/premake5.exe vs2019 --standalone
    displayName: "Premake Windows"
    condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )

#Compile with visual studio
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'RheaDev.sln'
      configuration: $(configuration)
      msbuildArchitecture: $(architecture)
    displayName: "Build Project"
```

Comment: Update: Re-downloaded the failing build from github & it doesn't work on local machines.

Answer (score 0):

Marked with GitLFS and the pipeline wasn't so the files were incorrect.